# declaring the session_start() function?

Tags: php

I am designing a login system using core PHP, please refer to the following code -

```
funciton login($username,$password)  {

//  mysql query to check the username and password

if($res == 1)  {

    session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
return true;

}

}
```

As you can see that I have started the session inside the login function, someone please tell me is it correct or do i start the session on every page of the applicaion i.e. in the common header file?

Comment: Add `session_start()` on top of the code instead.

Comment: This isn't really about sessions, but there's a typo in your function declaration

Comment: ok...you mean i need to start the session in the header file which is common in whole application...right?

Comment: `session_start()` should be on top (after `<?php` of every entry file you use. For example index.php, profile.php). If you use index.php and route the requests to appropriate controllers, then you only need to put it on index.php file.

Comment: it is recommended to use session_start() as the first statement of php  and that too on the top before anything gets as output. using it in function may cause issues when something gets as an output to browser before this statement reaches interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and see that the "session" that session_start() starts has nothing to do with being logged in or not. Start the session as one of the first things you do, in every script of your application (if your application needs any session management, that is).

The session represents the "visit" of a unique visitor on your website. A visit can, in theory, consist of consecutive login/logout pairs. It is still the same visit, but just a different login.

For example, if you have a "Choose a language" dropdown on your website, you may want to store the choice a user made in the session. When a user logs out, you still may want to preserve that chosen language. The information about a user being logged in or not is just one part of what sessions can do, so the session should be present independently of a possible login.

You can then store a "logged in" flag and a username in that session and just unset these two values once the visitor logs out.

Comment: I agree that "session" should not necessarily be treated as meaning "login session", but treating it as "visit" can be equally problematic, and clearing state on logout is generally a good idea. If some things need to survive, they could be copied into the new session, or just stored in separate cookies, with separate lifetimes, if they are not security sensitive (e.g. preferred language).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why clearing state is "generally a good idea"? I don't see any reason why you should clear everything, only to copy it to a fresh session after a logout.

Comment: It follows from the general principle that a whitelist is safer than a blacklist: If you clear only those parts that you think are sensitive, you might miss something; if you copy only those parts that you think are *not* sensitive, and clear everything else, the risk is much reduced.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` does not mean "create the session now", it means "open the current session if it exists, or create if it doesn't".

You may want to destroy the old session and create a new one on login/logout actions (there are various subtle security attacks like "session hijacking" and "session fixation" which it can be tricky to avoid).

But you will need to run `session_start()` on every page, in order to find out if the user is already logged in. If you don't, `$_SESSION` will be empty/undefined.